# How to extract images from pyspark dataframe to numpy

Tags: numpy, image-processing, pyspark, databricks

I am using Azure Databricks and reading images by:

```
image_df = spark.read.format("image").load("/FileStore/shared_uploads/images/")
```

How to extract images from PySpark's DataFrame to Numpy array?
When I was working on local machine with Jupyter Notebook I was using tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image img_to_array and load_img methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run .collect() on the dataframe to collect everything from the executors to the driver in the form of a list.

Don't do this unless you're absolutely certain that you have enough memory on your driver to hold the entire dataset.

You might want to consider using generators instead to load the images batch-wise:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=...)
```

then the `datagen.flow_from_directory(...)` method might be something to look into.